# splash screen list data, gives back an error in the item builder funcation

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to do a slider with multiple pics and texts. I have added the map list and the item bulider so preview the content, however it gives back this problem that says
image: splashData[index]["image"],
text: splashData[index]["text"],
(The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.) the problem is when I input the *image* and *text*. I have looked and nothing worng I did so far(hopefully)

```
  const Body({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  int currentPage = 0;
  List<Map<String, String>> splashData = [
    {
      "text":"ibrahim",
      "image":"assets/images/starter_pic.jpg",

    },
    {
      "text":"ahm",
      "image":"assets/images/starter_pic.jpg",

    },
    {
      "text":"salem",
      "image":"assets/images/starter_pic.jpg",

    },

  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: PageView.builder(
                onPageChanged:(value){
                  setState(() {
                    currentPage = value;
                  });
                },
                itemCount: splashData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => SplashContent(
                  image: splashData[index]["image"],
                  text: splashData[index]["text"],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: List.generate(
                      splashData.length, (index) => buildDot(index: index),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  AnimatedContainer buildDot({int? index}) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: kAnimationDuration,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
      height: 6,
      width: currentPage == index ? 20 : 6,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: currentPage == index ? kPrimaryColor : Color(0XFFC6AB59),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it has to have a safety null exit just like this.

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) => SplashContent(
    image: splashData[index]["image"] ?? '',
    text: splashData[index]["text"] ?? '',
```